# Operations with oriented angles

Tags: trigonometry, education, angle

If I have the figure below, how can I get the angle $a_2$ (the angle is >0 in counterclockwise direction)?

[image]

$$a_2 = \frac{\pi}{2} + a_1$$

or

$$a_2 = \frac{\pi}{2} - a_1$$
?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you get if you add the two equations together?

Comment: Hello @MattiP., I'll get $2 \, a_2 = \pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$|-\alpha_1| + \alpha_2 = \frac{\pi}2$$

since $$\alpha_2 = \frac{\pi}2 - |-\alpha_1|=  \frac{\pi}2 - |\alpha_1|= \frac{\pi}2 - \alpha_1$$

Comment: Hello @SiongThyeGoh, thank you very much for your explanation.